# Firebase Authentication State Reset Issue When Running Flutter Web App

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm encountering a Firebase authentication issue in my Flutter project while debugging the web version. Each time I run the web app, stop it, and then restart it, I'm automatically logged out. This behavior doesn't occur on iOS or Android.

```
  Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.2, on macOS 13.5.2 22G91 darwin-arm64, locale en-DE)
  Android Studio (version 2022.3)

  firebase_core: ^2.15.1
  firebase_auth: ^4.9.0
  firebase_core_web: ^2.7.0
  firebase_auth_web: ^5.8.0
```

Here are some code snippets that I'm using in my Flutter web app:

Query user at the start:

```dart
final firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().first;
// its always null at the first start when running in web
```

Stream to handle the user's authentication state:

```dart
_auth.authStateChanges().listen((firebaseUser) {
  _firebaseUser.add(firebaseUser);
});
```

Logging in with the following method:

```dart
var result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
  email: email, password: password
);
```

Additionally, I've experimented with the Persistence option for web as follows:

```
if (kIsWeb) {
  FirebaseAuth.instance.setPersistence(Persistence.LOCAL);
}
```

I've come across similar issues on github and stackoverflow, but it seems that they facing the issue after reloading the page and furthermore also on iOS / Android. I'm still logged in after reloading the page and on iOS / Android, everything is working as expected.

I'm wondering if this behavior is intended for Firebase on the web or if there are specific steps I should take to maintain the authentication state during debugging. Should I consider saving the Firebase user separately in shared preferences on the web to prevent this logout issue?

Any advice, insights, or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is that the web server always starts with a different port. If you run from command line, you can specify a fixed port like this:

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-port=50000
```

If you're using the VS Code extension to run/debug, you need to create a launch.json file where you can add a configuration that uses the fixed port:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "App Name (fixed port)",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "args": [
                "--web-port=50000"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yes indeed, that was the reason. Thanks for posting the answer ;)